# Access relationships

Tags: ms-access, foreign-keys, relational-database, primary-key

I have database with many tables. Couple ones from database are related to other one.

Arrangement of tables:

```
ID (automatic number with primary key), ID_sup (number), supplier (text), ...
```

Related table:

```
ID (number with primary key), supplier (text), address (text), ...
```

So in tables are the same `ID_sup` with `ID`, `supplier` with `supplier`. Tables contains only few suppliers from the table `Related table`.

I have tried to connect it with Enforce Referential Integrity + Cascade Updated Related fields but it doesn't work.

I have tried to change data types and primary keys as well but I have always these error messages:

1. Not found any unique index for linked primary table field.
2. Relationship must be on the same number of fields with the same data types. (Error 3368)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you want to have the Supplier's name duplicated (or "denormalized") in more than one table and have a Relationship automatically update the name in one table if it is changed in the other. However, Relationships don't (usually) work like that.

Instead, you keep the Supplier's name (and other Supplier-specific details) in *just* the [Suppliers] table, and then refer to the Supplier in other tables by the SupplierID *only*. This is called "normalizing the data".

Now, if you want to have the Supplier's name appear in a query (or report, etc.) about [Orders] then you JOIN the [Orders] table with the [Suppliers] table in your query, something like this:

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Orders.OrderDate, Suppliers.SupplierName
FROM Orders INNER JOIN Suppliers ON Orders.SupplierID = Suppliers.SupplierID
```

You can still use a Relationship to enforce Referential Integrity (i.e., make sure that every Order refers to a valid Supplier), but you do that with *just* the SupplierID and nothing else.

Comment: Gord, thank you very much for your answer - now it's much more clear. I am absolutely new in this field so sorry for my questions. Now, when I connected ID to ID suppliers it works. But first ID is automatic number so there would be any number. I would expect connection between ID_sup - ID but it doesn't work. Could you give me any explanation?

Comment: @astrak The `ID` AutoNumber field in the [Suppliers] table also needs to be specified as the `Primary Key` for that table. Did you do that? (When you look at the table in Design View that field should have a little "key" icon beside it.)

Comment: Yes - I have it. I finally solved it. So once again thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a one-to-many relationship from Table2.ID to Table1.ID_sup. In the MS Access "Edit Relationships" window, Table2.ID is on the left, and Table1.ID_sup is on the right. MS Access uses an infinity symbol to represent the "many" side of the relationship.